# Collapsing selected Game Objects in the hierarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am collapsing a selected parent gameObject with this editor script. It all works well but it also collapses other expanded gameObjects which should not happen. For example under two different parents, if I collapse one parent gameObject, even the other parent gameObject gets collapsed. How do I not let this happen?

I feel the problem is at `rootGameObjects.AddRange (SceneManager.GetSceneAt (i).GetRootGameObjects ());` where it takes the root gameObject in a scene but not the selected gameObject in the hierarchy.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public static class CollapseTools {
    private static int wait = 0;
    private static int undoIndex;

    public static void CollapseGameObjects () {
        EditorApplication.update -= CollapseGameObjects;
        CollapseGameObjects (new MenuCommand (null));
    }

    [MenuItem ("GameObject/Collapse GameObjects", priority = 40)]
    private static void CollapseGameObjects (MenuCommand command) {
        // This happens when this button is clicked via hierarchy's right click context menu
        // and is called once for each object in the selection. We don't want that, we want
        // the function to be called only once
        if (command.context) {
            EditorApplication.update -= CollapseGameObjects;
            EditorApplication.update += CollapseGameObjects;

            return;
        }

        List<GameObject> rootGameObjects = new List<GameObject> ();
#if UNITY_2018_3_OR_NEWER
        // Check if a prefab stage is currently open
        var prefabStage = UnityEditor.Experimental.SceneManagement.PrefabStageUtility.GetCurrentPrefabStage ();
        if (prefabStage != null && prefabStage.stageHandle.IsValid ())
            rootGameObjects.Add (prefabStage.prefabContentsRoot);
        else
#endif
        {
            int sceneCount = SceneManager.sceneCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < sceneCount; i++)
                rootGameObjects.AddRange (SceneManager.GetSceneAt (i).GetRootGameObjects ());
        }

        if (rootGameObjects.Count > 0) {
            Undo.IncrementCurrentGroup ();
            Selection.objects = Selection.objects;
            undoIndex = Undo.GetCurrentGroup ();

            Selection.objects = rootGameObjects.ToArray ();

            EditorApplication.update -= CollapseHelper;
            EditorApplication.update += CollapseHelper;
        }
    }

    private static void CollapseHelper () {
        if (wait < 1) // Increase the number if script doesn't always work
            wait++;
        else {
            EditorApplication.update -= CollapseHelper;
            wait = 0;

            EditorWindow focusedWindow = EditorWindow.focusedWindow;
            if (focusedWindow != null)
                focusedWindow.SendEvent (new Event { keyCode = KeyCode.LeftArrow, type = EventType.KeyDown, alt = true });

            Undo.RevertAllDownToGroup (undoIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you know that holding Alt while clicking collapses objects recursively in hierarchy?

Comment: Yes but I am trying to achieve it with an editor script.

Comment: @Richard what is the use of it though, if this is already a built-in functionality? ^^

Comment: @derHugo Just wanted to apply it as an editor script :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

When it comes to Unity, nothing beats reflection:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

internal class MyClass : EditorWindow
{
    private void OnGUI()
    {
        using (var scope = new EditorGUI.DisabledGroupScope(Selection.activeGameObject == null))
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button("Expand Recursive"))
            {
                var type = typeof(EditorWindow).Assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.SceneHierarchyWindow");
                var window = GetWindow(type);
                var exprec = type.GetMethod("SetExpandedRecursive");
                exprec!.Invoke(window, new object[] {Selection.activeGameObject.GetInstanceID(), true});
            }
        }
    }

    [MenuItem("TEST/TEST")]
    private static void Init()
    {
        GetWindow<MyClass>();
    }
}
```

Check `SceneHierarchyWindow` class for other things you could hook into.

Now you have another problem, when you have multiple hierarchy windows open, I'll let you solve that one :)

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer but it contradicts my question. My question is to collapse the already expanded selected gameObject, but not to expand them. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Yes, use `false` instead. Check the source of SceneHierarchyWindow to understand how it works.

Comment: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/SceneHierarchyWindow.cs

Comment: Okay I shall try that, I am getting two errors in your script, ```(11,23): error CS1002: ; expected``` and ```(11,24): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'```

Comment: That's because it's C# 8, I guess you just have to remove the ! in exprec!.Invoke.

Comment: Can it also be achieved with a right click on gameObject and then selecting collapse/expand. Like how you did in OnGUI(), can I achieve this with a right click?

Comment: Sure I suppose it should work. In case it doesn't you may want to wrap it in a EditorApplication.delayCall to execute at next frame since the context menu might keep Unity in a blocking state.